# plpgsql function no results

Tags: arrays, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have done the following function in plpgsql. It works fine and the it returns `'OK'`, BUT for some reason it inputs nothing in the table `temp`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_route(node integer[])
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
    i int := 0;
    _r record;
    vertex int;

BEGIN

    FOREACH i IN ARRAY node

    LOOP

    IF( i < (array_length(node, 1) - 1))

    THEN

        FOR _r IN EXECUTE 'select * from shortest_path(''
                   select id as id, source_id::int4 as source, target_id::int4 as target, cost, reverse_cost
                           from network_of_point'','|| node[i] ||','|| node[i+1] ||', true, true)'

        LOOP
            vertex := _r.vertex_id;

            EXECUTE 'insert into temp
                 select nextval(''road_intersection_id_seq''), point
                 from distinct_network_point
                 where distinct_network_point.id ='|| vertex;

        END LOOP;

    i = i + 1;

    END IF;

    END LOOP;

RETURN 'OK';

END;$BODY$
```

The following is the synatx I am using to call the function:

```
select get_route('{2,7}')
```

Comment: Do you do `COMMIT` after you call the function?

Comment: What do you mean by commit?. Obviously I have done execute on the query if you mean so. @IgorRomanchenko

Comment: try to print the value of vertex just before the execute. If it's null the query will fail.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? using raise notice? @DavideBerra

Comment: `RAISE INFO 'vertex: %', vertex;`

Comment: it just printed 'OK'. Without any vertex value

Comment: it has to do something with the synatx of the array because it is not even passing from fromm the foreach loop @DavideBerra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because this line

```
IF( i < (array_length(node, 1) - 1))
```

You're testing if `2` or `7` (taken from your example) are less than the length of the array, that's valued `2`.

That's because your next queries are never executed.

Comment: BUT i STILL GET NULLE ERROR. How can I refer to an element of the array like for ex: node[i+1] @DavideBerra

Comment: You don't have to care... foreach will do it for you... the value of every element of the array is stored into the i variable (that's not an index). Put a RAISE INFO 'I VALUE: %', i; just after the first LOOP and you'll get what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line, inner part of code never executed.

```
IF( i < (array_length(node, 1) - 1))
```

Actually you are extracting value of `i` from node array

```
FOREACH i IN ARRAY node
```

which has value `2` or `7` as in your example and you are treating `i` as node index which is wrong. I have created a separate `int` variable value, now we can use `i` as array index.

*I think you want to achieve this.*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_route(node integer[])
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    i int := 1;
    _r record;
    vertex int;
    value int;

BEGIN

    FOREACH value IN ARRAY node
    LOOP
        IF( i < (array_length(node, 1)))
        THEN
            FOR _r IN EXECUTE 'select * from shortest_path(''
                select id as id, source_id::int4 as source, target_id::int4 as target, cost, reverse_cost
                        from network_of_point'','|| node[i] ||','|| node[i+1] ||', true, true)'
           LOOP
            vertex := _r.vertex_id;
            EXECUTE 'insert into temp
                select nextval(''road_intersection_id_seq''), point
                from distinct_network_point
                where distinct_network_point.id ='|| vertex;

           END LOOP;
        i = i + 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 'OK';
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Instead of using node[i] you can directly use value.